how to export an excel data to generate an bar graph in ppt using openxml and c#
The process is read the excel data using maybe EPPlus and then use that data to create a new ppt and generate the bar graph using openxml and C#. I am testing out code which I will provide in this git link here - https://github.com/Bhaskar365/Excel_To_PPT_OpenXml_CSharp.git.
The things I have been trying is read excel data from EPPlus and then generate the chart after creating a new powerpoint. The problem is if I extract the generated powerpoint file using 7-Zip I get this file
*[Content_Types].xml file -
<Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation.main+xml" />

<Default Extension="bin" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />

<Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" />

<Override PartName="/ppt/slides/slide1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide+xml" />

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml" />

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideMasters/slideMaster1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideMaster+xml" />

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideMasters/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml" />

<Override PartName="/ppt/slides/charts/chart1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml" />

<Override PartName="/ppt/slides/charts/colors.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-office.chartcolorstyle+xml" />

<Override PartName="/ppt/slides/charts/style.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-office.chartstyle+xml" />

Out of this this is the spreadsheet code whose extension is important - Default Extension="bin"
Here extension is showing bin i.e., binary but the extension should be xlsx
If I generate one powerpoint with bar chart directly by inserting it in ppt, then this is the xml extraction -
<Default Extension="jpeg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>

<Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>

<Default Extension="xlsx" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/>

<Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/presentation.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation.main+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideMasters/slideMaster1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideMaster+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slides/slide1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/presProps.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presProps+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/viewProps.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.viewProps+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/tableStyles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.tableStyles+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout2.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout3.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout4.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout5.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout6.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout7.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout8.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout9.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout10.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout11.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/charts/chart1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/charts/style1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-office.chartstyle+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/ppt/charts/colors1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-office.chartcolorstyle+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>

<Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>

*
This is the xml markup for a file that has file generated from the charts section in ppt which is done as Insert -> Chart -> bar -> stacked bar :
Extension is xlsx not bin or binary as was generated from OpenXml and C#. Need the code to make the binary extension into xlsx using code correctly.
Any help is appreciated.
The only issue I have is that value embedded in the powerpoint needs to be of type System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(theExcelData)) after the excel value is converted from base64string and thus the memorystream value does not get embedded to the powerpoint and graph is not generated for some reason. Any help is appreciated.
